# Manage inter-project dependency with Gradle configurations

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my Android project, I have a folder whose content is generated by a gradle task, and I need to package this folder as assets for the .apk I build. Initially, this is how I am setting up my gradle build file:

```
android {
   ...
   sourceSets {
       main {
           assets {
               srcDir generatedAssetsDir
           }
       }
   }
   ...
}
...
afterEvaluate { evaluated ->
   evaluated.tasks.getByPath("packageReleaseAssets").dependsOn evaluated.tasks.getByPath('taskThatGeneratesTheAssetsDir')
}
```

Now I am trying to avoid using `afterEvaluate`, so I followed this [example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html#sec:simple-sharing-artifacts-between-projects) and created two gradle projects, one acting as producer and one as consumer. The relevant portions of the producer project’s build.gradle looks like:

```
abstract class MyTaskClass extends DefaultTask {
   @OutputDirectory
   abstract DirectoryProperty getOutputDir()

   @TaskAction
   def run() {
       def src = new File(getProject().getRootDir().toString()+'/in/src.txt')
       def dst = new File(getOutputDir().get().getAsFile().toString()+'/dst.txt')
       dst << src.text
   }
}

tasks.register("myTask", MyTaskClass) {
   outputDir = new File(getProject().getRootDir().toString()+'/out')
}

configurations {
   prepAssets {
       canBeConsumed = true
       canBeResolved = false
       extendsFrom implementation, runtimeOnly
   }
}

artifacts {
   prepAssets(myTask.outputDir) {
       builtBy(myTask)
   }
}
```

While the build.gradle file of the consumer looks like:

```
configurations {
    assetsConsumer {
        canBeConsumed = false
        canBeResolved = true
    }
}

android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets {
                srcDir configurations.assetsConsumer
            }
        }
    }
    ....
}

dependencies {
    assetsConsumer project(path: ":mylibrary", configuration: 'prepAssets')
    ...
}
```

The idea is that when myTask inside the producer runs, it should create a text file inside <Project_Root>/out/ folder. This folder is then specified as the Android assets folder in the consumer project.
However, when I try to perform a gradle sync, I get this strange error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:assetsConsumer'.
Could not create task ':app:generateDebugLintModel'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:assetsConsumer'.
Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.
The value of this property is derived from:
  - task ':app:generateDebugLintModel' property 'outputDirectory'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong with Gradle configurations?

Comment: It looks like some of your question is duplicated. Can you double check that the content is as you'd expect, please?